# Jquery increase input box values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        minDate: -0
    });
    $(".minus").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(4);
        var value = parseInt($("#value_" + id).val());
        if (value == 0) return false;
        newval = parseInt(value) - 1;
        $("#value_" + id).val(newval)
    });
    $(".plus").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(5);
        var value = parseInt($("#value_" + id).val());
        newval = parseInt(value) + 1;
        $("#value_" + id).val(newval)
    });
    $(".value").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
            // let it happen
        } else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

This is my current code however its not working here is the following i want :
I have 20 input boxes <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> buttons all with a diffrent counter. 
HTML example:

```
<tr>
    <td><h4>Mozzarella met honing, tomaat en basilicum</h4></td>
    <td width="100" valign="top">EUR 3,75</td>
    <td width="150">
        <input type="hidden" name="naam_3" value="Kaas - Mozzarella met honing, tomaat en basilicum">
        <input type="hidden" name="prijs_3" value="3,75">
        <div class="minus" id="min_wit_3">-</div>
        <input type="text" class="value" id="value_wit_3" name="aantal_3_wit" value="0">
        <div class="plus" id="plus_wit_3">+</div>
        <div class="minus" id="min_bruin_3">-</div>
        <input type="text" class="value" id="value_bruin_3" name="aantal_3_bruin" value="0">
        <div class="plus" id="plus_bruin_3">+</div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Boerenbrie</h4></td>
    <td width="100" valign="top">EUR 4,00</td>
    <td width="150">
        <input type="hidden" name="naam_4" value="Kaas - Boerenbrie">
        <input type="hidden" name="prijs_4" value="4">
        <div class="minus" id="min_wit_4">-</div>
        <input type="text" class="value" id="value_wit_4" name="aantal_4_wit" value="0">
        <div class="plus" id="plus_wit_4">+</div>
        <div class="minus" id="min_bruin_4">-</div>
        <input type="text" class="value" id="value_bruin_4" name="aantal_4_bruin" value="0">
        <div class="plus" id="plus_bruin_4">+</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Whenever i click the <kbd>+</kbd> button it has to be 1 and when i click it again it has to be 2 and so on.
When i click the <kbd>-</kbd> button it does the reverse but it can't go below 0. 
Hopefully anyone knows the solution for this. < br />

So basically i need 1 code for multiple input boxes

Website : http://www.verruklik.nl/bestelformulier/
Try and press the + button nothing happens, while de script seems correct.

Comment: Please only post the relevant sections of your code. Posting an unformatted wall of code is not really making it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @Scoobler if I could rep you for that, I would.

Comment: Also, try to be more specific. What are you trying to do that you can't?
Don't expect people just do everything for you. A http://jsfiddle.net/ would be great, as well.

Comment: I used jsfiddle.net , i made a code for it http://jsfiddle.net/zRX2D/528/ however this is just for 1 id.
Here is the live code: http://www.verruklik.nl/bestelformulier/
the problem is when i press the + button it doesn't go up while the script seems to be functioning.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan NP, I find it quicker to format the code and read through it than I do to try and read the code un-formatted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted in the question, works - the reason the script isn't working *here* is due to the `datepicker`.

Check the code [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6eJm/3/) with the datepicker removed.
Check the code *as posted* [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6eJm/4/) doesn't work with the datepicker.
Check the code working with the datepicker [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6eJm/5/) *Note the added resources (on the left, click manage resources).*

On your site, you have included two versions of jQuery UI 1.7.2 and 1.8.14 *(lines 36 and 37)* this could have caused a conflict and can break the javascript.

There is another error on your site which could also be breaking things: 
`Error: $("ul.sf-menu").supersubs is not a function`
`Source File: http://www.verruklik.nl/js/onLoad.js`
`Line: 1`

A tip for finding breaks in your code, use the browsers console where possible.
If you are using Google Chrome, IE9 press `F12` or Firefox with the web developer extension press `CTRL+SHIFT+J`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition to your `$(".minus")` click handler to check if it would make the value less than zero.

```
$(".minus").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(4);
    var value = parseInt($("#value_"+id).val());

    if (value == 0) 
        return false;

    newval = parseInt(value) - 1;
    if (newval < 0)
        newval = 0;

    $("#value_"+id).val(newval)
});
```

Comment: This just solves the negative amounts, thanks for that though.